# Pharo code formating issues

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

In Pharo 2.0 image, when i try to format my code on nautilus browser i get the code scrambled in an unexpected way.

For example

```
testStrings
| a b |
a := 'AAAAA'.
b := 'BBBBB'.
^a,b
```

If this method is typed and after saving, try to format it. What i got was this, note the duplicated string-

```
testStrings
    | a b |
    b := 'BBBBB'.
    b := 'BBBBB'.
    ^ a , b.
```

Has anyone come across this before? Any way out of this?

Comment: So the problem is that `b := 'this is second string'.` appeares twice instead of original code?

Comment: this is perfect valid behavior. Usually we format methods the second way, you will see that when you browse other methods. What is it that you do not like in particular?

Comment: @dh82 no, look better, 'this is second string' appears twice.

Comment: @dh82 the first line of my code gets replaced with my second line. Pls can any one try this and let me know if they are also getting the same behaviour.Thanks guys..

Comment: @Uko yes this is it. Did you get the same result ..?

Comment: This is a bug. Please report on bugs.pharo.org. In this report, could you please tell us which version you are using exacty? You can get this information through the World Menu -> System -> About... I am interested in the "Latest update:" field.

Comment: I cannot reproduce from a fresh download Pharo2.0 Latest update: #20608

Comment: @DamienCassou 

Pharo2.0
Latest update: #20596 Should i try to update to latest as aka.nice suggested ? can i load all latest from Pharo2.0 repository in ss3. I am a bit new to pharo but so far i am here to stay..;-)

Comment: @aka.nice yes you are right. The latest image dont seem to have the issue. I would like to have a suggestion , should i update my existing image from repository  or should i get the new image and load all the stuff on to that. Seaside, Glorp and some of my own are the additions.Also iam not able to register to Penelope plus the mailing list seems to avoid my mails.:-)

Comment: @GRThushar I believe that the 'System>Software update' in world menu should just work... The best is to try it. Make a copy of your .image .changes just in case.

Comment: @aka.nice the update went well. another reason to love pharo. but it seems the formatting problem persists. So i decided to debug , and finally i found that RBLiteralValueNode has been moved to unclassified, i am not sure how this happened. So i loaded the latest from AST core and formatting is good. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the AST-Core package reloaded from the repo and the problem was solved. it seems something i loaded in the image caused some of the AST classes(like RBLiteralValueNode) to 
move to Unclassified package, and also some instance vars were undeclared. This cause the formatting statemets preparation to fail. however on loading all latest it solved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I tried to reproduce this problem in the latest Pharo 2.0 and I could not... it formats perfectly fine.

Do you load any other packages in addition? Maybe something that breaks the AST formatter?

Comment: to be frank this image has been with me for a while. and i have been playing with it pretty aggressively.so i am not sure which particular action caused the trouble. any way i will be looking out for it and will report to you if i get a clue. might come in handy for the community.also thanks to aka.nice , i did the latest update and seems the image is all set for my further developement.